# Use 'this' in Vue template?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

I'm mixed in my head : I don't know why I see somewhere that we can use `this` in Vue.js template. Now I don't know which I must use.

I test some case here :

```js
new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data: function() {
   return {
     myVar: 'test'
    }
  },
  methods: {
    returnText: function() {
     console.log('methods returnText !');
      return 'return text from methods !';
    }
  },
  computed: {
    computedProp: function() {
     return 'computed !';
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.2.5/vue.js"></script>

<div id="app">

  {{ this.myVar }}<br><!-- this works -->
  {{ myVar }}<br><!-- this works -->
  <button @click="myVar = 'test without this !'" type="button">
          Change text</button><!-- this works --><br>

  <button @click="this.myVar = 'test with this !'" type="button">
          Change text (not working because of 'this')</button><!-- this NOT works -->
  <br><br>
  
  {{ computedProp }} <!-- this works -->
  <br>
  {{ this.computedProp }} <!-- this works -->
  
  <br><br>
  {{ returnText() }} <!-- this works -->
  <br>
  {{ this.returnText() }} <!-- this works -->
</div>
```

What is the recommendation ?

Comment: not using `this` is the one I see everywhere, and why type 5 chars more, if result is same. :)

Comment: At least in some cases using `this` causes issues, as you noticed. One other place I found is in `v-for`. With Vuex you can't do `this.$store...` within `v-for` but `$store...` works fine. So the recommendation to not use `this` is qutie sensible.

Answer (score 4):

In template you don't need to use `this`, you use `this` in functions like `mounted()`, `created()`, or in `methods`, etc. **All lifecycle hooks are called in this context pointing to the invoking Vue instance.**

https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/instance.html

Answer (score 0):

I assume v-bind acts like js native 'bind' function, e.g. binds function to another object, different than our context ( which is Vue instanse in other cases).