# Vuetify select not returning selected object

Tags: javascript, vuejs2, vuetify.js, vuex

I'm new to js and vue and I encountered problem. I've got v-select component (from vuetify) defined like this:

```
      <v-select
        label="Department"
        v-model="this.department"
        :items="this.factoryElements"
        item-text="name"
        return-object
        single-line
        @change="test"
      ></v-select>
```

this.factoryElements - array of elements from store (referenced by getter from vuex)

this.department - has it's value assigned to null

@change="test" - logs this.department to console

I want my v-select to return entire object so i use return-object prop. V-select component sees and displays items properly but when i try to select an item it returns 3 errors

[Errors logged to console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ziiWm.png)

The null at the end of the log is this.department logged to console by method test.

I will appreciate all help :)

Comment: Do not use `this` in templates.

Comment: It seems more like a code preference to me, but i agree it looks better without this, BUT it has nothing to do with the problem stated above :/

Comment: You are wrong! Using `this` in template **is a problem**! **NEVER** use `this` in Vue templates...

Comment: Hmm, could you tell me why is this a problem then? It seemed to work fine, are there some edge cases then?

Comment: Ohh i think i found an answer for that, here's link for the thread https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43188317/use-this-in-vue-template
. Thanks then, you were right :)